# "Space" vs "area" around

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to know if *area* and *space* can be considered as perfect synonyms when they are used to refer to regions surrounding a physical object, as in this sentence:

> This zone is applied to the **area/space** within the pumping station, the **area/space** around the storage tank 5m in diameter, and 1m above the opening for filling.

I'm aware that there are contexts when these two words can't be used interchangeably but in contexts as in this sentence I can't see that use of one or the other word changes the meaning in any way.

Comment: Inasmuch as I don't know what it is supposed to mean that a zone is "applied to" either a "space" or an "area", I'm inclined to agree that the sentence is equally meaningless either way.

Comment: I have a mild preference for space since it is 3-D and area is nominally 2-D. *Area* can be used to suggest a footprint plus the space directly above it. But I wouldn't worry too much about it unless this was some sort of contentious regulatory matter.

Comment: PellMel: Zones are assigned to certain areas within the facility according to certain parameters, so they can be managed more easily. "Zones are applied" is an appropriate collocation in such context, although I'm not saying that there aren't more established phrases for that, like "zoning is done" or similar.

Comment: An area is typically thought of as 2-dimensional, and a space as 3. But maybe in your context the area within a pumping station really means the volume, or maybe the height dimension is unimportant - in those cases, sure, area ~= space.